# Android - Dagger injection at runtime

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, dagger

i need to inject the class at runtime using dagger. what my problem is am getting compile time error while injecting the class locally in method and also i was not able to inject at runtime without using constant for @Named

Example

```
interface PerformActionInterface{
      fun performAction()
}

class P1 : PerformActionInterface{
   override fun performAction(){
   }
}

class P2 : PerformActionInterface{
   override fun performAction(){
   }
}


class PerformAction @Inject constructor(){

      fun perform(name : String){

        @Inject
        @Named(name)
        performActionInterface : PerformActionInterface

        performActionInterface.performAction()
    }
}
```

were as in dagger implementation i will be doing like this

```
 @Binds
 @Named("p1")
 abstract bindP1Class(p1 : P1) :PerformActionInterface

 @Binds
 @Named("p2")
 abstract bindP1Class(p2 : P2) :PerformActionInterface
```

Any help for how to inject this at runtime ?

Comment: Can you post the errors you get?

Comment: please include stacktrace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't annotate something in runtime, [the element value in Java annotation has to be a constant expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7.1).

But this use case can be solved by map multibind.

In your `Module`, in addition to just `@Bind` or `@Provide`, also annotate the abstract fun with `@IntoMap` and the map key (sorry for any error in my Kotlin)

```
@Binds
@IntoMap
@StringKey("p1")
abstract fun bindP1Class(p1: P1): PerformActionInterface

@Binds
@IntoMap
@StringKey("p2")
abstract fun bindP2Class(p2: P2): PerformActionInterface
```

Then in your `PerformAction` class, declare a dependency of a map from `String` to `PerformActionInterface`, and do whatever with the map:

```
// map value type can be Lazy<> or Provider<> as needed
class PerformAction @Inject constructor(
        val map: Map<String, @JvmSuppressWildcards PerformActionInterface>) {

    fun perform(name: String) {
        map.get(name)?.performAction()
        // or do something if the get returns null
    }
}
```